# Animating maps based on database values

Tags: c#, java, .net, flash, animation

### [Image link to GUI Requirement http://imageshack.us/a/img39/8062/requirement1.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img39/8062/requirement1.jpg)

1. The image map should be loaded from a database
2. On entering values in search box , it should query the database and zoom to that coordinate,and fill up the results on the left hand side
3. On querying the status, the total villages belonging to this status should be displayed on the map
4. On clicking the coordinates of the villages on the map ,the left result should be displayed.
5. We should be able to update the status , name ,coordinates of the village selected.
6. We should also be able to add new village.
7. This should be a desktop-application (if possible)

---

I have the design in mind but do not know what software , language, framework to use? I have been searching for the right solution but could not get what i desire.
 Any ideas/ suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Vanlal

Comment: Try to ask at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you're in java, I would recommend GeoTools and the Java Topology Suite.
http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm
http://www.geotools.org/