# Convert jpg file to mapping file

Tags: .net, image, dictionary, gis

I have a image map file which is of JPEG file extension. I want to convert this file to either one of the below:

1. .shp files
2. .tiff (geotiff) file with tcw file

For the first one, using QuantumGIS, I was able to get the shp file, but it is not similar to the original map.

For the second one, using QuantumGIS, I can get the tiff file, but I do not have the tcw file which is needed.

This is the first time I am working on GIS application software, so any hints/advice how to proceed will be greatly appreciated.

I am using .NET dotspatial to develop this application.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have a jpg of a map, and you want to convert this to a shapefile?
This won't work.
Or do you want to geo reference it?

Comment: yes i have jpg of a map, i can georeferenced it using quantum gis , but my development tool can take only shp files..so i need the shp file.

Comment: Why do you think that tiff should come with tcw? tcw is TurboCAD vector format, and tiff is raster. Georeference information of tiff may come in tfw (world file).

Comment: Sorry it should be tfw file now tcw file, sorry for the mistake. How can i make the tfw file for tiff?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a shape file from a raster image.*
A shp-file usually contains, easy spoken, some vectors and metadata.
You may create a shape file on your own with a rectangle, which has the same coordinates than the map (so that the corner points of the rectangle have the same coordinates than the corner points ouf your map image). 
I'm not sure how this works in qGIS, but you may reference the jpg then to the rectangle shp you created.
After you referenced it you'll have to add all the needed informations (streets etc.) on your own.
But keep in mind that it is not possible to create a shape file containing all the informations automatically from a raster image.

Learn more about shp-files here: http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

For GIS releated questions take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/
(* if you find a good, clean and easy way to do this, you'll earn a lot of money)

Comment: * Of course, he can. It is called vectorization. In QuantumGIS under the Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector) menu. Or manually draw each feature, but this is time-consuming.

Comment: Yes, but the result is, in my mind, not acceptable. There will be no meta data. And the time correcting wrong shapes might be bigger than creating it on your own. Vectorization needs very good input material and a lot of luck. The quality will never be as good as doing it on your own.

Comment: I can create the shp file from the raster image .. If you have a simple map like nothing inside but just the boundary , it gives me the correct shp files, all i do is georeference the map. But the map i am working with is quite complex, so the shp file i am getting is very difficult to understand not like the original map.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to georeference your jpeg raster in QuantumGIS, so you have done it. You can also check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xcqzEpoRuok&lr=1).

Assuming that you need not .tcw but .tfw world file, you can try to export tiff through File > Export > Export Raster > r.out.gdal. Actually, you can write the [world file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file) manually for your tiff.

For getting a shapefile, you can vectorize your raster automatically (Raster > Conversion > Polygonize (Raster to vector) menu, check [this](http://confound.me.uk/maps/ppv4.pdf)) or manually (again see the video).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, i was busy with some other project. The shp files that is generated is very difficult to understand. I do not know how to make it look nice(i.e like the actual map).

Comment: So, you trying to work with [this map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464612/animating-maps-based-on-database-values)? And you want to do what you wrote there? For that map it is easier to manually vectorize the boundaries and the cities-points.

Comment: how do i vectorised this jpg map, i tried with qGIS , but the output is way way different .. I am trying to developed in .net , i have finished the functional part but with a different shape files.. but i need the correct shape file ..